# How to concatenate django countries with primary key to create custom code

Tags: python, django, custom-code

Below is my Participant class. I want to create a custom code that concatenates the country field with the auto-generated primary key. Whatever I've tried till now has failed, can anyone help me, please. The structure of the code is supposed to be the country first and the primary key second. I need this because when I print my report the code should be present in it

```
class Participant(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_Name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    country = CountryField()`enter code here`
    trainer = models.CharField(choices = trainer, max_length=100, )
    gender = models.CharField(choices= gender, max_length=50)

    title = models.CharField(choices= title_Choice, max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True )


    contact_address = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=True, null=True)
    work_phone = models.CharField(max_length = 30, blank=True, null=True)
    fax_number = models.CharField(max_length = 100, blank=True, null=True)
    home_phone = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField
    #previous_employment = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    organization = models.ManyToManyField(Organization, blank=True)
    #role = models.ForeignKey(Role,  on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    education_level = models.CharField(choices = education_level_choice, max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)


    comments = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=True, null=True)
```

views and HTML for the data table

views.py

```
class Index(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    template = 'index.html'
    login_url = '/login/'


    def get(self, request):
        session =   Session.objects.all()
        participant = Participant.objects.all() 

        num_participant = Participant.objects.all().count()


        return render(request, self.template, {'participants': participant} )
```

index.html

```
 <table class="table table-bordered" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
                                        <thead>
                                            <th>First name</th>
                                            <th>Surname</th>
                                            <th>Country</th>
                                            <th>Gender</th>
                                            <th>Organization</th>
                                            <th>Trainer</th>
                                            <th>Session</th>
                                        </tr>
                                        </thead>

                                    <tbody>
                                    {% for participant in participants %}
                                       <tr>
                                          <td>{{ participant.first_name }}</td>
                                          <td>{{ participant.last_Name }}</td>
                                          <td>{{ participant.country }}</td>
                                          <td>{{ participant.gender }}</td>
                                          <td>{{ participant.get_organization }}</td>
                                          <td>{{participant.trainer}}</td>
                                          <td>{{ participant.host_participant.all }}</td>
```

Comment: You are probably going to have to make a custom `save` method to make that work.

Comment: Do you possibly have an example?, I just need this particular concatenated field for my reports. I'm still a beginner in python and Django.

Comment: Are you printing this report through Django? And if so, what is your code for printing the report?

Comment: I haven't written the code yet, still trying to learn how to. But I just added in the views and the HTML file, I've been trying to show the concatenated field in the HTML data table but haven't been successful yet.

Comment: `<td>{{ participant.country }}{{ participant.id }}</td>`  ??? That should display what you want.

Comment: Wow, it worked thank you very much, sir.